# Getting RecejtedExecutionException after 1 task is completed

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am getting this exception

```
Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@341cf993 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@122db90f

[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(300);
...
collection.forEach(x -> { executorService.submit(new SenderThread(sender, params));});
executorService.shutdown();
```

This collection is 10-20 elements and when I execute it, it completes the execution for the first task then it gives RecejtedExecutionException and does not complete other tasks.

Do you have any suggestion for overcoming this issue?

Comment: Are you `submit`ting more tasks after calling `shutdown()` - e.g. does the `SenderThread` runnable itself `submit` new tasks? Calling `shutdown()` will directly reject new `submit`s and this seems to be the most likely issue.

Comment: No this is the only usage of this executor service. SenderThreads does not submit new tasks. And if it was the case that other tasks are submitted, would not  the queued tasks increase?

Comment: Is this really the code you use then? The `ExecutorService` will not accept new tasks and reject them immediately when `shutdown()` has been called - is this code somehow called twice? That would mean the executor is already shutdown on the second call and explain your issue. I think we need more of the real code / context as your example seems fine to me.

Comment: This code is called from a service so it is possible that it is called more than once. But everytime it is closing after executing 1 task from the call. That seems odd to me. I suspect that somehow the threadpool only accepts 1 element but I do not know why.

Comment: Is it a good practice to remove shutdown if there is such a possibility of rejecting all following tasks, will it have side effects? Or creating the executorservice in the method? I am now creating it on the class definition.

Comment: You should only `shutdown()` the `ExecutorService` when you are finished processing. If this is a web application and is used for handling some tasks for the whole time the application runs, you should only  `shutdown()` when your application exits. 

Basically: We know now that the method that `submit`s new tasks and calls `shutdown()` is called more than once which means the second time its called its already shutdown and not accepting new tasks, creating the exception you see. Either start a new executor for each method call (most likely not what you want) or shutdown later

Comment: Thanks @roookeee I will close it on program exit